# CopSSH backspace doesn't work in bash?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, 64-bit, cygwin, copssh

I just installed CopSSH Basic Edition v2.1.2.5 on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit box...I've only installed it because PuTTY doesn't have a working IPv6 version yet, and I want to connect to another IPv6 connected computer using it.

When I try to use the (I'm assuming cygwin) bash shell that it installs, when I backspace I don't get the usual backspace behavior, the cursor kinda moves forward or something, but that doesn't always happen, other times it displays the output from eariler in the line, it's hard to explain...

Comment: Additional information about IPv6 support in PuTTY:  http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ipv6-build.html

Comment: So it's in the nightly's eh?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh!  Did I just inadvertently solve your problem?  If so, great!